# How to get the url of image in descripttion tag of xml file while parsing?

Tags: python, django

I am trying out parsing using urllib and beautiful soup.I can get the title, description and link I can,t bring the url of image.
This is what the code am tried.
views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from os.path import basename, splitext
import os
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def parser(request):
    source_txt=urllib.urlopen("http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533928/index.rss")
    b=BeautifulSoup(source_txt.read())
    arr=[]
    for p in b.findAll('item'):
        d={}
        d['title']=p.title.string
        d['description']=strip_tags(p.description.string).strip(';&nbsp')
        d['guid']=p.guid.string
        for q in p.findAll('description'):
            for r in q.findAll('img'):
                d['img']=r['src']
        arr.append(d)
    return render(request,'temp.html',{'arr':arr})
```

html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% for i in arr %}
 <p>{{i.title}}</p>
 <p>{{i.description}}</p>
 <p>{{i.guid}}</p>
 <img src="{{i.img}}" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><hr>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out to proceed further......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS is nothing new you know? So use the right tool for the job instead of the BeautifulSoup hammer...

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser