# django xml parsing -parse img src attribute inside the xml tag

Tags: django, python-2.7

I need the URL inside the description tag of RSS file. I am trying to parse the images in the following link.
"ibnlive.in.com/ibnrss/rss/shows/worldview.xml"
I need the image link in that. I am using urllib and beautiful soup to parse details.
I am trying to parse the title,description,link and images inside the item tag. I can parse the title, description and link. But I can't parse image inside the description tag.

#### XML:

```
<item>
    <title>World View: US shutdown ends, is the relief only temporary?</title>
    <link>http://ibnlive.in.com/videos/429157/world-view-us-shutdown-ends-is-the-relief-only-temporary.html</link>
    <description>&lt;img src='http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/sitepix/10_2013/worldview_1810a_90x62.jpg' width='90' height='62'&gt;The US Senate overwhelmingly approved a deal on Wednesday to end a political crisis that partially shut down the federal government and brought the world's biggest economy to the edge of a debt default that could have threatened financial calamity.</description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 18 Oct 2013 09:34:32 +0530</pubDate>
    <guid>http://ibnlive.in.com/videos/429157/world-view-us-shutdown-ends-is-the-relief-only-temporary.html</guid>
    <copyright>IBNLive</copyright>
    <language>en-us</language>
</item>
```

#### views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
from os.path import basename, splitext
import os
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def international(request):
    arr=[]
    #asianage,oneinindia-papers
    a=["http://news.oneindia.in/rss/news-international-fb.xml","http://www.asianage.com/rss/37"]
    for i in a:
        source_txt=urllib.urlopen(i)
        b=BeautifulSoup(source_txt.read())
        for q in b.findAll('item'):
            d={}
            d['desc']=strip_tags(q.description.string).strip('&nbsp')
            if q.guid:
                d['link']=q.guid.string
            else:   
                d['link']=strip_tags(q.comments)
            d['title']=q.title.string
            for r in q.findAll('description'):
                d['image']=r['src']
            arr.append(d)
    return render(request,'feedpars.html',{'arr':arr})
```

#### HTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {% for i in arr %}
             <p>{{i.title}}</p>
             <p>{{i.desc}}</p>
             <p>{{i.guid}}</p>
             <img src="{{i.image}}" style="width:100px;height:100px;"><hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Nothing gets displayed in my output.

Comment: It's the fourth time you're posting basically the same question with the same code snippets.

Comment: Am new to python and django.I have started learning just before a month. I have collected nearly 100 news sites and am trying to bring title, description, image and link beneath the title of each and every url. The xml file differs from each and every url. For the previously asked questions I just searched in google and done it on my own. I need to bring it like google news. For some urls I have done it as such in google news. But for some links I got a trouble. The posted answers are suggesting me to learn feed parser instead of using beautiful soup.

Answer (score 0):

1/ as I already told you here [How to get the url of image in descripttion tag of xml file while parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19563227/41316) : this is a rss feed so use the appropriate tool: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser

2/ there's no proper "img" tag in the description, the html markup has been entity-encoded. To get the url, you have to either decode the description's content (to get the tag back) and pass the resulting html fragment to your HTML parser or - since it will probably not be as complex as a full html doc - just use a plain regexp on the encoded content.